# How to set 'max_parallel_threads', 'max_parallel_experiments' for BACKEND_OPTIONS in QuantumInstance

Tags: qiskit, programming

In QuantumInstance there are `max_parallel_threads`, `max_parallel_experiments` in `BACKEND_OPTIONS` - Wondering whether the backend I am using supports parallel-threads or experiments and how to use this features? How do I find out whether my backend supports this?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is a programmatically way to know the `backend_options` supported by each backend. I always check the documentation on each backend to see what are the options. For example for `UnitarySimulator`, these are the backend options https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.providers.aer.UnitarySimulator.html?highlight=backend_options

Comment: well, you can check the options the backend supports using something like ``backend.configuration().max_experiments`` for the backend you are using. However, I could not find a way to set the above options.

Comment: It's a fair point. I'll submit a feature request.

Comment: https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-terra/issues/5208